# How to eliminate Error when installing web3.py

Tags: python, pip, web3py

I am attempting to install web3 on my windows machine. I am using the Visual studio code terminal to do this. I have used both commands.

1. pip install web3
2. pip3 install web3

The first error I was getting was around the Visual studios build tools which I was able to install. Now when I run the command I get this error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ealvarado\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nfyoy3t_\\cytoolz_9d52991e4515405886466c30cd8781ec\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ealvarado\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nfyoy3t_\\cytoolz_9d52991e4515405886466c30cd8781ec\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ealvarado\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-g88od3fy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Please don't post images of errors. Instead, add the error as text and put it in code formatting. For the source of your error, web3 ist only supported up to python 3.9, see the [pypi page(https://pypi.org/project/web3/). Python 3.10 is quite new. Do you absolutely need it? If not, try to use an older version

Comment: Can you post the full log, or at least all relevant lines? The warnings are not so relevant, but the error is, and that is probably a summary of something that happened before, so the earlier log lines probably contain important information.

Answer (score 2):

the `WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)` is because at some point in time pip failed to delete some temporary folder that it make while updating or installing or something, to get rip of it just go to the folder listed and delete the folders which name start with `~`.

The other warning is for you to upgrade your pip, you should do that.

And for the error, I don't know, maybe that library don't support python 3.10 yet and that is why it fail and/or your outdated pip don't fetch the most current version by virtue of being outdated